# How to declare variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, var

Sorry for the newb question. But I have been trying for hours.

```
var dbruns = {}; // namespace

dbruns.dbstuff = {
    var nameslistresult = [];
```

This gets an error, unexpected identifier. When I put it at the dbruns level

```
var dbruns = {}; // namespace
var nameslistresult = [];
dbruns.dbstuff = {
```

It gets past there, but then

```
console.log(typeof dbruns.nameslistresult);
console.log(typeof dbruns.dbstuff.nameslistresult);
```

both return undefined.

I really have no idea what is going on here, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `dbruns.dbstuff = {nameslistresult:[] };` or `dbruns.dbstuff = {};dbruns.dbstuff.nameslistresult = [];` Have you already tried to read documentation or tutorials before "trying for hours"?

Comment: Thank you so much! Indeed I did, I didn't see anything about how to define properties. I presumed they were public variables. Since they kind of are.

Comment: Just to save a bit of face, the thing that drove me to try ever more bizarre attempts at making the code work was because the underlying API was broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be confusing variables and properties.

This is how you declare a variable (and assign it an empty object as a value using the object literal syntax):

```
var dbruns = {};
```

This is how you assign a value to a property of an object:

```
dbruns.dbstuff = { …
```

This is how you construct an object literal with predefined properties:

```
… = {
    nameslistresul: [],
    foo: bar
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately javascript does not have name-spaced blocks, but rather functions act as enclosures.

The first error you are getting is because you are not defining a namespace, but defining a javascript object, and then puting unexpected expressions in there instead of property definitions...

```
var dbruns = { key: "value", another_key: "another value" } // valid syntax for object definition
```

If you want `nameresults` to be a property of `dbruns` you can do...

```
var dbruns = {}
dbruns.nameresults = []
dbruns.stuff = {}
```

Javascript uses prototypal inheritance, and everything in javascript is an object.